# Custom logic in tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

where can I put custom logic or which function should I overload to add custom logic in tastypie. For example: want to return `CustomObject` which contains `name` in uppercase, but before returning I want to make it lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to provide custom stuff like that, I recommend doing it during `dehydrate`. Check out the [documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#dehydrate-foo), the example is pretty much what you're looking for:

```
class MyResource(ModelResource):
    # The ``title`` field is already added to the class by ``ModelResource``
    # and populated off ``Note.title``. But we want allcaps titles...

    class Meta:
        queryset = Note.objects.all()

    def dehydrate_title(self, bundle):
        return bundle.data['title'].upper()
```

Well, except you're looking for `.lower()` of course :)

```
class CustomObjectResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = CustomObject.objects.all()

    def dehydrate_title(self, bundle):
        return bundle.data['name'].lower()
```

Comment: Thanks @msc, maybe this is my fail of asking question. What I want is overriding get, post, put behavior. Let's say as an example, whenever user sends query to `get` I will increase counter for this object and when user sends `post` query, first I will check for special rights and then give access to change some data

Comment: For the get, this could also be done in the dehydrate cycle, check out dehydrate(). http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#advanced-data-preparation

Comment: For put, post and get use apply_authorization_limits() for access

Answer (score 0):

You can IMHO override any field:

```
class CustomResource(ModelResource):

    name = fields.CharField(
        attribute='get_lowercased_name', 
        readonly=True 
    )

    class Meta:
        queryset = Custom.objects.all()
```

And you need to define `get_lowercased_name` method on your `Custom` model class.

Comment: Thanks @Michal above was only to provide with example and seems not good example, since solved using standard API. What I want is doing some logic before returning data, but I don't know where can I put that logic.